# Splitting $\mathbb Z_{pq}$ into direct sum with $\mathbb Z_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, prime-numbers, chinese-remainder-theorem, direct-sum

I'm  trying to show there exists   $T \subseteq \mathbb Z_{pq}$ 
such that $\mathbb Z_{pq} = \mathbb Z_p \oplus T$, where $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes.

I tried to use Chinese Remainder so we know $\mathbb Z_{pq} = \mathbb Z_p \times \mathbb Z_q$. Not sure what to do next.

Comment: Hint: consider $T=\{x\in \mathbb{Z}_{pq}: qx=0\}$.

Comment: @egreg I don't follow, isn't qx=0 only when x=p?

Comment: When $x$ is a multiple of $p$. Indeed $T$ is no other than $p\mathbf Z/pq\mathbf Z$.

Comment: @Bernard I see so T will be a group of order q?

Comment: Yes, it is isomorphic to $\mathbf Z/q\mathbf Z$.

Comment: If you know that $\mathbb{Z}_{pq}$ has a normal subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p$, do you not also realize it has one isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_q$?  The roles of $p$ and $q$ are interchangeable in this problem.

Comment: @Bernard Alright so I think I've figured it out, we can let $ T=Z_q $

Comment: $\mathbf Z/q\mathbf Z$ is *not* a subset of $\mathbf Z/pq\mathbf Z$. If you eventually want an isomorphism, it's OK. It's not if you want an equality.

Comment: @TheProblem Also $2p,3p,\dots,(q-1)p$. And that's the hint. `;-)`

Comment: I don't understand, what do I have to do to get an equality? @Bernard

Comment: Consider $p\mathbf Z/pq\mathbf Z$, as @egreg hinted.

Comment: I'm going to need a little more to go on. I realise that is isomorphic Zq and that's about it. @Bernard

Comment: Maybe this detail on the isomorphism helps?\begin{align*}\mathbf Z/q\mathbf Z&\to p\mathbf Z/pq\mathbf Z\subset\mathbf Z/pq\mathbf Z\\k+q\mathbf Z&\mapsto pk+pq\mathbf Z\end{align*}

Comment: Not really, I don't understand what we are trying to show. What is T? If it's pZ then isn't it surely equal to Zq? @Bernard